# How does Google Fences API work?

Tags: android, google-api

I want to ask a simple question.
How does Google Fences API (https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview) work? Espescially the activity recognition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the [Fence API Overview](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview) mentions:

> ...the concept of "fences" is taken from geofencing, in which a
> geographic region, or "geofence", is defined, and an app receives
> callbacks when a user enters or leaves this region.
>
> The Fence API
> expands on the concept of geofencing to include many other context
> conditions in addition to geographical proximity.
>
> An app receives
> callbacks whenever the context state transitions. For example, if your
> app defines a fence for headphones, it will get callbacks when the
> headphones are plugged in, and when they are unplugged.

In basic terms you define a geographical area (defined by GPS coordinates) so that when a user enters or leaves this "geospace" a notification is sent out. See the following image

[image]

Comment: Nice thank you for the explanation...
I want to ask further question, how about the activity recognition? I mean how this API can detect if you are in vehicle, walking, running, etc..
Does it detect by the location movement and the movement speed or accelerometer, or something else.